# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function, $A =\{y \in \mathbb R: y = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n}),$ for a sequence $x_{n} \to + \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $A$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $A =\{y \in \mathbb R: y = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n}),$ for a sequence $x_{n} \to + \infty\}$.  Then the set $A$ is necessarily $-$

$a$ compact set

$b$  closed set

$c$  Singleton set

$d$ none of these

My attempt :

If I take the function $f(x) = \sin x$ and $x_{n} = n \pi$ and another sequence $y_{n}$ for same function $\sin x$ that converges to $1$ or $-1$. Then, I'll have at least two element in $A$ so it is not necessarily a connected set. But this set is compact as well as closed.

I don't know how to choose between other three options. 
Can I find a set $A$ such that it's not bounded or it's not closed?

Comment: The set for $\sin(x)$ is connected. Every element in $[-1,1]$ occurs as a limit.

Comment: It's given in question, "for a sequence" I didn't paid attention to it. Also, for a sequence I could find only one element in A.

Comment: @Paul K I took sin x as function, and $n\pi$ as sequence, then $f(x_{n})$ converges to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a. $A$ may not be a compact set**

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x \le 0\\
x \left(\sin x +1 \right)& x>0
\end{cases}$

You have $A = [0,\infty)$

**c. $A$ may not be a singleton set**

$f(x) = \sin x$

$A = [-1,1]$.

**b. $A$ is a closed set**

If $(y_n)$ is a sequence of $A$ converging to $y$, use a diagonal argument to build a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = y$. Proving that $y \in A$ and that $A$ is closed.

**FINALLY, THE RIGHT ANSWER IS b.**

Comment: So I can choose a continuous function and sequence, if I take the set of all limit points of $f(x_{n})$ then I will get $A$, since there always exists a subsequence converging to a limit point. Then I have the counterexamples you mentioned. Now, since the set of limit points is a closed set, so d is correct. Am I right?

Comment: No, as b. is correct, d. is not the right answer.

Comment: Yes , I meant 'd'. It was typing error. But what I got from your answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.